# Semantic html tags and classes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a simple question about html5 semantic tags. If I am writing code with bootstrap which of the following is the right way to code? Can we or should we write classes into semantic tags, or we should write divs inside semantic tags and then in those divs classes?

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="row justify-content-between">
       <div class="col-md-6">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
       </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
         <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
         </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to go with the first one - option b means you don't have a direct container for your row so it may act weirdly.  Also, you can put classes on any html element you want - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header have a look at the attributes section

Answer (score 0):

Don't add elements you don't *need*. Style existing ones wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is fine to add classes or id's to any valid markup such as `<header>`

In your case option a is correct

```
//css
 .cls{ 
     //CSS style rules
  }

//html
<header class='cls'>TitleName</header >
```